# Вставить ajax success в перемену js

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Ajax запрос выполняется с интервалом в 5 секунд, `ajax.php` возвращает число от нуля до 50. Как проверить если больше 0 тогда включить мелодию ?
Js:

```
setInterval(function () {

         var id = '1';
        $.ajax({
            url : "ajax.php",
            cache : false,
            type : "POST",
            data : {id : id},
            success : function (res) {
                $("#id_ajax").html(res);

                var rez_ajax = 5; //пример

                if ( rez_ajax > 0) {
                    $('<audio id="chatAudio"><source src="audio/notify.ogg" type="audio/ogg">').appendTo('body');
                    $('#chatAudio')[0].play();
                }
            }
        });

    }, 5000);
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
    echo "5";
?>
```

Comment: ну так смотрите что вам в `res` приходит, это и используйте

Comment: @BOPOH Cпасибо за подсказку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось очень просто, если функция `success` возвращает только цифры, тогда просто переменную `res` вставить в `if`.

```
   if ( res > 0) {
          $('<audio id="chatAudio"><source src="audio/notify.ogg" type="audio/ogg">').appendTo('body');
         $('#chatAudio')[0].play();
    }
```